# textfile content is not visible in non-main java file but visible in main java

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. and In my project I have three java class.
and third java class is Notification.java(which is not main java)and here I am trying to 
 display content of text file  using text view,but is does not display anything. but when I take it as  example  project where Notificaion.java is main java file,then it is able to display textfile content. I know I am missing some small logical thing.

**Notification.java**

```
package com.example.alarmnotification;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class NotificationView extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       /*int[] quoteArray_june = {
        R.raw.june,
        R.raw.june
      };*/      
      setContentView(R.layout.notification);

      TextView QuoteTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quoteTxt);
      QuoteTxt.setText(readTxt());    
   }

   private String readTxt(){

      InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.june);

      ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      int i;
      try {
         i = inputStream.read();
         while (i != -1)    {
           byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
           i = inputStream.read();
           i--;
         }
         inputStream.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
   }
}
```

and notification.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    >
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/prabhupada_Quote"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
       <TextView  
 android:id="@+id/quoteTxt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:textSize="22px"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you calling this file ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Image view might be hiding the Text View
2. If the resource file contain "Readable Text" Use the following method to read the String

   ```
   public String readStringFromResource() {

          StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
          String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

     try {
       InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.june);

       BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(is), 1024 * 8);
       try {
           String line = null;
           while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
               contents.append(line);
               contents.append(sep);
           }
       } finally {
           input.close();
       }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

      } catch (IOException ex) {

     }

    return contents.toString();
    }
   ```